# Android multiple Listviews on single activity not showing items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I have an activity with 2 Listviews- PairedListView and NewDevicesListView and a scanbutton. Initially, onCreate() the activity should display all the bluetooth paired devices and the scan button. On pressing Scan button, it should display the 2nd listview with new devices. To do so i used multiple linear layouts. However, my problem is that neither lists are displaying any item at all.

here is the layout-

```
    <devicelist.layout>
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".DeviceList"
                tools:ignore="ExtraText" >

              <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1" >

                 <TextView android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/title_paired_devices"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:background="#666"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"

                />
                <ListView android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:stackFromBottom="true"


                />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/title_new_devices"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/title_other_devices"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:background="#666"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                />
                <ListView android:id="@+id/new_devices"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:stackFromBottom="true"

                />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button android:id="@+id/button_scan"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button_scan"

                />


            </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the java class

```
<devicelist.java>
                package org.example.spark;

            import java.util.Set;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
            import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
            import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.content.IntentFilter;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.view.Window;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.TextView;


            public class DeviceList extends Activity {
                   // Return Intent extra
                public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

                // Member fields
                private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
               private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
                private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                     // Setup the window
                    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_devicelist);

                    // Set result CANCELED incase the user backs out
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);


                    // Initialize the button to perform device discovery
                   Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
                   scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            doDiscovery();
                      v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     }
                  });

                    // Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and
                    // one for newly discovered devices
               mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

                    // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
                   ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
                  pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
                pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

                    // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
               ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
                newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
              newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

                    // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

                    // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
                    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
                    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

                    // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
                    mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

                    // Get a set of currently paired devices
                    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                    // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
                 if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                     findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
             } }
                 else {
               String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
                   mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                 }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onDestroy() {
                    super.onDestroy();

                    // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
                    if (mBtAdapter != null) {
                        mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    }

                    // Unregister broadcast listeners
                    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
                }

                /**
                 * Start device discover with the BluetoothAdapter
                 */
                private void doDiscovery() 
                {


                    // Indicate scanning in the title
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                    setTitle(R.string.scanning);

                    // Turn on sub-title for new devices
                   findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // If we're already discovering, stop it
                    if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering())
                    {
                        mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    }

                    // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
                    mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
                }

                // The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
                private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
                        mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                        // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
                        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
                        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

                        // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

                        // Set result and finish this Activity
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                };

                // The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
                // changes the title when discovery is finished
                private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        String action = intent.getAction();

                        // When discovery finds a device
                        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                          //   If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if(device.getBondState()!= BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

                        // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                  setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                  setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                  String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
               mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                            }
                        }
                 }
                };





                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_devicelist, menu);
                    return true;
                }

            }
```

Can any1 pls tell me where i could be going wrong?

EDIT

Hey i modified the code as follows for both adapters.. is this the right way? i tried running after the modification still there were no items displayed..

```
                        // Get a set of currently paired devices
                    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                    // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
                 if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                     findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing something similar to the below code.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html. Look at the .documentation for more info

```
 public class YourActivity extends Activity 
 {
private ListView lv;
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
      setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
    // populate arraylist with string data
     ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
     your_array_list.add("foo");
     your_array_list.add("bar");

     // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);
     lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
}
}
```

Edit

You can add data to your arraylist as when you scan devices.

notifyDataSetChanged()
Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

After getting new data you can update listview by calling notifyDataSetChanged()on your adapter.

Comment: hey, this is in case if we already have an array of items right? but in the application, the array is dynamically growing as it finds the bluetooth devices..

Comment: After you added an item dinamically execute an arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();